# e2e tests on namespace's age

Tags: kubernetes, testing

I wrote a really simple code to delete every namespace older than X days in a kubernetes cluster.

Now I want to add tests to my function and check if a namespace is deleted or not.
The basic idea was to create a cluster before launching my e2e tests with everything I need (here some namespaces with different timestamp). Then launch my tests and check if everything is ok.

The problem is that I haven't found something to change a namespace age.

Does anyone have an idea how to get a cluster than I can easily test?

Thank you.